# Multiple jQuery regex test

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to perform multiple regex test on input filed.
Below the script:

```js
$("#search-registration").keyup(function () {
    var input_data = $('#search-registration').val();

    var regexTest = function() {
      this.withPrefix = /^[iI]-[a-zA-Z]{4}$/;
      this.noPrefix = /^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/;
    }

    if(regexTest.withPrefix.test(input_data) || regexTest.noPrefix.test(input_data)) {
      console.log(input_data);
      $( "div.result" ).html(input_data);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-registration" name="regcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<div id="result">

</div>
```

I'm not able to perform the double regex and I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
What am I doing wrong? Honestly I'm not able to figure out the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the 'new' keyword before function, like this:

```
  var regexTest = new function() {
      this.withPrefix = /^[iI]-[a-zA-Z]{4}$/;
      this.noPrefix = /^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var regexTest = Object({
  withPrefix : "/^[iI]-[a-zA-Z]{4}$/", 
  noPrefix : "/^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/",
  test : function (input_data) {
      //test code here
  }
});
```

Instead of

```
var regexTest = function() {
  this.withPrefix = /^[iI]-[a-zA-Z]{4}$/;
  this.noPrefix = /^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback. Tried it but got the following error: Uncaught TypeError: regexTest.withPrefix.test is not a function

Comment: @Federico I updated my answer with how to define the `test` function

Comment: Thanks a lot for further help AmmoPT, I completely missed your solution...I need to learn more about it. Thanks for pointing me on that